# Difference between variadic template struct with std::array and c style array member

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

So recently I tried to make a following struct:

```
template<int... Factors>
struct Data
{
    static constexpr int arr[sizeof...(Factors)] = {Factors...};
};
int main()
{
    Data<1, 2, 3> p;
    cout << p.arr[0] << " " << p.arr[1] << " " << p.arr[2] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And it works fine.

However if I switch `static constexpr int arr[sizeof...(Factors)] = {Factors...};` with `static constexpr std::array<int, sizeof...(Factors)> arr {Factors...};` the code above sends me an

> undefined reference to 'Data<1,2,3>::arr'

error.

Since I am fairly new to variadic templates I  was wondering what's the difference between those two, and why does the error occurs?

Comment: [It works for me](https://ideone.com/hXAEkj). Are you sure you didn't forget `#include <array>`? Or something?

Comment: Rakete1111, you're right it works. But I found out gcc version 5.2.1 needs to use, at least optimization 1 flag (for some reason), so this works:
`g++ -O1 -std=c++11 main.cpp -o output`
but this gave me an error:
`g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o output` when I run it through the terminal

Answer (score 1):

You should add this

```
template <int ... Factors>
constexpr std::array<int, sizeof...(Factors)> Data<Factors...>::arr;
```

outside the struct.

And I suggest a double level of braces for inizialization

```
static constexpr std::array<int, sizeof...(Factors)> arr { { Factors... } };
```

Comment: Just curious: Why double braces?

Comment: @Rakete1111 - short answer: to avoid the annoing warning from clang++ ("suggest braces around initialization of subobject") :( - long answer: because a `std::array` is a `class` (a `struct`?) that contain a C-style array, so you need a level of braces for the class and a level of braces for the contained C- style array (in C++11; no more true in C++14; but this question is tagged C++11)

Comment: Your short answer is *the* explanation :) You can also use `=` instead (I would prefer that)

Comment: @Rakete1111 - yes: the short answer is the real one :) ; I've tried with `=` (and only a level pf braces) but clang++ give me the same warning (in C++14 too; and this is a defect of clang, I suppose)

Comment: Probably :) That's weird, `std::array` normally supports aggregate initialization, which shouldn't give off a warning, oh well.